# How to disable Syncfusion's Autocomplete from moving to the next entry when completed?

Tags: xamarin, autocomplete, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion's `Autocomplete` entry in Xamarin.Forms in a way not related to a form. Thus, I don't want it to step to the next `Entry` object in the UI. However, doesn't matter what I try doing, when finishing putting in the input, it jumps to the next `Entry`.

I have tried setting both `Entry`s `IsTabStop` to `False`, as well as setting the second one's `TabIndex` to be smaller the other one's. Nothing worked, the only think which I have found to work is disabling the second `Entry` while the other one is focused.

#### XAML:

```xml
<ScrollView ...>
    // ....

    <StackLayout>
        // ....
        <autocomp:SfAutoComplete x:Name="TagsAutoComplete"
                                 WidthRequest="100"
                                 NoResultsFoundText="New Tag..."
                                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                 Keyboard="Chat"
                                 IsTabStop="False"
                                 IsVisible="False"
                                 Completed="AddTagAutoComplete_Completed" />
        // ....
    </StackLayout>

    // ....

    <Frame>
        <Grid>
            // ....
            <Entry FontSize="18" TextColor="Black" 
                   WidthRequest="150" VerticalOptions="Center"
                   Unfocused="EquValueEntry_Unfocused" 
                   TabIndex="-1" IsTabStop="False" />
            // ....
        </Grid>
    </Frame>

    // ....
</ScrollView>
```

My workaround uses the `Focused` and `Unfocused` methods of the `Autocomplete`, which simply set the `IsEnabled` property of the second `Entry` to `False` and `True` respectively. Does anyone have a better, more elegant solution?

Comment: How do you finish putting in the input, before it jumps to the next Entry? Could you provide more details for me to reproduce?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, I would love to give more details, however I am not sure what you would need. To finish putting in the input, I simply press the `=>` button at the bottom right of the keyboard. A tick mark doesn't show, only a "continue" type of symbol.

Comment: I used your code and try tp reproduce. But there is only one entry in my page. I could not  reproduce how it jumps to the next Entry.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, what do you mean by one entry? The `SFAutoComplete` is one entry, and the `Entry` is the other. What other information would you need to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please check my Screenshot. When i finish the `SfAutoComplete`, the focus would not jump to the next entry. https://imgur.com/nxkviV7 If i do not click to focus the Enrty, it would not jump to the Entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would like to let know that you can stop the next Entry focus by Return type and IME option.

**UWP:**

Setting IsTabStop as false it disables the next Entry focus.

**Android:**

By changing the input method options of EditText in autocomplete (using ImeOptions property)

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SfAutoComplete> e) 
    { 
        base.OnElementChanged(e); 
        if (Control != null) 
        { 
            Control.GetAutoEditText().ImeOptions = Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done; 
            Control.GetAutoEditText().SetImeActionLabel("Send", Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done); 
        }
```

iOS:

By changing the return type property of UITextField in autocomplete (using ReturnKeyType property)

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SfAutoComplete> e) 
    { 
        base.OnElementChanged(e); 
        if (Control != null) 
        { 
            Control.TextField.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done; 
        } 
    }
```

We have prepared a sample for your reference get it from below link.

**Sample:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/AutoComplete_EntryNotFocus1409818301

For more information refer the link:
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10690/how-to-change-return-button-type-in-sfautocomplete